# How can I install a user CA certificate from a .pem file?

Tags: certificates, google-pixel-4a

I have a .pem file and -key.pem. I'm on a Pixel 4a with Android 13, and when I go to Settings -> Security -> Advanced Settings -> Encryption -> Install certificate -> CA certificate, I can select one file. When I select the .pem file it just goes back to the Install certificate screen, and when I choose the -key.pem file it says that I need a private key to install it.
I don't know much about SSL certificates so help would be very much appreciated :)

---

Edit: I am using mkcert to generate a certificate for a certain IP address in my network. I am using KDE connect to send the files to my phone.

Comment: For what purpose do you want to install the certificate? Wifi WPA enterprise auth or VPN or just a custom root CA e.g. for traffic interception?

Comment: @Robert I'm developing a mobile website that requires https to function. I want to host it locally for testing, but when I do it says the site is not secure, so I want to give a certain IP an ssl certificate.

Comment: Have you checked if your certificate has been added in the Trustworthy Login Data -> User list? If the certificate is present make sure to use the full DNS name in Chrome addressbar that is saved in the certificate.

Comment: It is not there, I don't think it's installing. Just for conformation, is this how installing a certificate works?

Comment: Yes, this is the way it is supposed to work. I just tried to with an [example custom ROOT CA](https://rootca.allianz.com/download/Allianz_Group_Root_CA_II_base64.cer) certificate from a large insurance company and it works, you get a toast message "Certificate installed". May be the chosen certificate you are trying to install is invalid? Where does this certificate come from, how was it generated?

Comment: I am using mkcert to generate a certificate for a certain IP address, and I sent it to my phone with KDE connect, I will add this info to my question.

Comment: @Robert I was able to successfully install the example CA, but I can't find any difference between it and my CA, when I changed my .pem file to a .cer file there was different behavior but it still didn't work.